# Select Distinct value Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my simplified table

```
year | teacher
1    | john
2    | john
2    | sam
3    | john
3    | simon
```

When I run the query below

```
SELECT year, teacher FROM table1 GROUP BY year
```

It gives me the result :

```
year | teacher
1    | john
2    | john
3    | john
```

In this case, year column is fine as it shows all distinct value, however teacher column is still repeated. I wish to have distinct values on teacher columns too.

Output I am looking for :

```
year | teacher
1    | john
2    | sam
3    | simon
```

Comment: That is not the way how you should write [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) queries in anny SQL database.

Comment: Also why should the SQL query result into john for year 1, sam for the second year and simon for the 3 year? SQL is defined to be orderless tables/resultsets looking into this datamodel the expected resultset does not make much sense.

Comment: `SELECT MIN(year) AS year, teacher FROM table1 GROUP BY teacher`, but it is not clear why you would want this logic.

Answer (score 1):

This query is not valid SQL (even if MySQL happens to accept it):

```
SELECT year, teacher
FROM table1
GROUP BY year;
```

You need an aggregation function around `teacher`:

```
SELECT year, MAX(teacher)
FROM table1
GROUP BY year;
```

That said, this doesn't do what you want.  That is hard to do in a single query.  Instead, use two queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year FROM table1;

SELECT DISTINCT teacher FROM table1;
```